# Getting "Error not a statement" on compile

Tags: java

```
                            case 2: int n;
                            int fact;
                            fact = 1;
                            System.out.println("What is your number");
                            n = scan.nextInt();
                            for (i >= n; i++;)
                            {
                                fact = fact*i;
                            }
                            System.out.println("The factorial of" + n + fact);
                            System.exit(0);
```

Case 2 thats apart of a larger chain that returns an error saying "i >= n" is not a statement.

Comment: Try `for (; i >= n; i++)`  You have semicolon in wrong spot if you are not going to use all the options (or `for (int i = 0; i >= n; i++)` if you just forgot to declare `i` at all).

Comment: Aa for loop needs three parts: `for(initialization; termination; increment)`.  Your loop has the termination condition where the initialization should be, the increment where the termination condition should be, and no increment.  Try this instead: `for(int i = 0; i >= n; i++)`.  Here's the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for for-loops.

Comment: @Jordan You don't _need_ 3 parts for a `for` loop though, you just need 2 semicolons.  There is the classic `for (;;)` infinite loop which is the same as `while(true)`, and this is leaving out `for-each` of course.  Oh yeah your link even mentions all three parts are optional.

Comment: @Nexevis True, but based on the posted question, all three are needed in this particular situation.

Comment: you need 3 parts, even if the 3 are empty ones - `for()` or `for (;)` does not compile [:-)

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger The documentation specifically says all three parts are optional, if you think of it as two semicolons are required or three empty parts that is just semantics.

Comment: @Jordan He could have declared `i` before the `switch`, we do not have enough information to infer which he needs.

Comment: @Nexevis see the `[:-)` at the end of my previous comment

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger Sorry, hard to understand intent through text sometimes, also your smiley face is confusing it has a face going both directions.

Comment: it is just a (strange)hat

Answer (score 0):

First statement should be initialisation statement in for loop. Read it -
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html